# Web-based or hosted remote access software

Tags: web-apps, remote-access

I'm looking for web-based or hosted remote access software (like Teamviewer) for our helpdesk staff, with no client installation necessary.

Most of our customers use a business network where no installation is allowed. It should work for Windows, Apple and Linux machines.

Comment: If no installation is allowed for a business network, there is a reason for that.  Best practice would be going through that business network.  Teamviewer is still top on my list.

Comment: Teamviewr has client installation necessary. What do you mean by "client installation"? Can't run a setupe.exe that will access the registry, etc? Would it be ok if they have to download a portable software?

Comment: I am stuck behind a corporate firewall at the moment, which is very restrictive of what it will ;let me browse, so this will be a comment, rather than an answer. If you are interested, I can post a much fuller answer later from home. What you want is a VNC   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing   Personally, I made a comparison a few years ago and since then I have been totally satisfied with http://www.tightvnc.com/  However, if your users are not allowed to install, but are allowed to user portable apps, try http://sourceforge.net/projects/pvnc/

Answer (score 1):

try [ISL Online](http://www.islonline.com/). It works on Windows, Mac and Linux. Included in license are mobile apps which allow mobile device support and supporting remote computers from a mobile device. 
It's a very secure and reliable software, used also by Konica Minolta and AVG Technologies.

Comment: It comes with a hefty price.

Comment: The software is priced per concurrent connection - that is the number of sessions active at the same time, $469 (339€) for one concurrent connection per year to be precise, 2 x $469 (339€) for two, with bulk discounts starting at three concurrent connections. There is no additional charge per technician, per workstation, per host, per client or any other costs for that matter. Other than paying for the number of concurrent connections your company needs, you can use the software without other limits. Including mobile applications. More on [ISL Online's pricing] (http://bit.ly/1LapCPK)

Comment: I wouldn't know the rate of use of your software but even huge companies count their pennies because it adds up.  I am not a network person but I closely experienced their concerns when it came to budget.  Unless the one session is a very important one.

Comment: I agree, companies, also huge ones, do care about the cost. That's why we have a no hidden cost policy, we do our best to make our pricing as transparent as possible. The client knows the price he/she pays includes everything, all the updates, all the upgrades, all the mobile applications, unlimited installations, hosts and clients you connect to. Only limit is the concurrent connection.

Answer (score 0):

I  am stuck behind a corporate firewall at the moment, which is very restrictive of what it will let me browse, so I can't copy/paste from the site to quote from it.

However, what you need is [Join Me](http://www.join.me) which bills itself as exactly what you want.

It allows anyone to remotely view and control anyone else's PC, so long as they both type in the same password (agreed upon by telephone).

There's not much more to say, really, otherr that it is free.